# Starter of engine cfm56-3C

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

Pls ask me i really need to know this.
After the engine CFM56-3C start and light up can i disconnect it's starter from it? In order to put it on onother engine for starting process?!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about the starter that is connected to the accessory gearbox? You want to remove that while the engine is running?

Comment: Yes the starter that is connected to accessory gear box. I want to remove it after the engine start and stability. Can i?!

Comment: The starter air discharge duct is used by the VSV system as a fuel drain, and is connected to a bleed valve in the 5th stage of the compressor. I doubt just removing the starter is sufficient. Anyway the MEL would not allow to fly with only one engine restartable in flight. [Picture of the AGB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyAsU.jpg), the starter is connected to the big vertical air duct, just above the generator.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend

Comment: If your boss really wants to do this (or presses you for reasons why you can or cannot do this), you should contact CFM product support (https://www.cfmaeroengines.com/customer-support/) and ask them. They are the only ones that can truly answer a question like this.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a valid theoretical engineering question. In which aspect is it less clear/useful than [Can a fighter jet be stolen?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/37019/3201) or [Is this plane landing or departing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/34586/3201) which had 138 upvotes and only one downvote? All the contrary, upvote it!

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's suggested amounts to taking an engine apart while it is running. The amount of risk involved for the mechanics would be immense, if it's even possible at all.

If one makes enough assumptions about what risks one is willing to accept, what condition the running engine is in afterwards (presumably still running, not necessarily airworthy), how extensive the preparations are for such a stunt (i.e. somebody may have to create a procedure & checklists from scratch), and so on, all sorts of crazy things can be ***possible*** to do.

But as far as remotely practical or safe, no, taking something as big as the starter off of a running engine isn't something you're likely to see happening.

Some turboprops (the C-130, for one) can start the engine with the starter removed -- a high-speed taxi up to about 100 knots and then a gentle abort, on a sufficiently long runway is all that's needed.  But pulling (and padding!!!) the starter from a *running* engine? No, thanks!

Comment: @MhZerafat You want a reference for why it is a bad idea to open and take apart a running turbofan engine? How about "common sense"?

Comment: I know this is a terrible idea. I just wanna know is this possible with all the risks that can cause bad events.